# Shell script to fetch part of file name from input file and transform it into output file

Tags: shell-script

Source_FIle:

```
/path/to file/A_B_C_D_201507290915.csv
```

Destination_File should be like :

```
/some/other/path/to file/A_B_C_D_201507290915.csv
```

I need to transform Source_FIle and storing with the same name in some other location.

Transformation is like converting all the rows of csv in column.
CODE used:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`echo A_B_C_D_*.csv | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)'`
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){A[NR,i]=$i};if(NF>n){n=NF}}
END{for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
for(j=1;j<=NR;j++){
s=s?s","A[j,i]:A[j,i]}
print s;s=""}}' A_B_C_D_*.csv > /some/other/path/to file/A_B_C_D_$var.csv
```

It is working fine for one file but in case of multiple source files its giving ambiguous redirect error.

Comment: Are you transposing the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `var` variable. If you want to stick to it, rather assign it to an array.

#### Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`echo A_B_C_D_*.csv | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)'`
arr=($var)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do

    awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){A[NR,i]=$i};if(NF>n){n=NF}}
    END{for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=NR;j++){
    s=s?s","A[j,i]:A[j,i]}
    print s;s=""}}' A_B_C_D_$i.csv > /some/path_to/dest/A_B_C_D_$i.csv

done
```

Comment: Yeah you are right its working fine now .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filename variable in awk

Not sure what you are setting var for so i will leave that out

```
awk -F, '{
          for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)A[NR,i]=$i
          if(NF>n)n=NF
         }
         ENDFILE{
              sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME)
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                  for(j=1;j<=NR;j++){
                      s=s?s","A[j,i]:A[j,i]
                  }
                  print s > "NEWPATH" FILENAME;s="" 
              }
         }' A_B_C_D_*.csv
```

Comment: this will use the last filename, modern awk have a `ENDFILE` clause that should be use.

Comment: @Archemar Yeah ,my bad, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @Archemar, well I am not so sure if this isn't yet another GNUism (i. e. `gawk`)...as I prefer my `awk` lines to remain portable, I always have to care for this fact...

Answer (score 0):

Use `basename`, part of `coreutils`.

Using `bash`:

```
for i in $(<file_with_source_file_names) 
 do  
    mv $i /some/other/path/to\ file/$(basename $i) 
 done
```

Or you could use `cp` instead of `mv`. Your choice.

Comment: OP have a transformation step. (awk ... )

Comment: OP has a _task_ and is overcomplicating it.

Comment: @Allen and OP seems to always use new username per question ;-) look [this "question"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220279/transform-csv-file-using-shell-script?rq=1). Same user. 100.0% sure.